# Change volume icon in panel

Tags: settings, wingpanel

I have uninstalled pulseaudio and for this place I installed gnome-alsamixer. But icon from pulse audio still is in top panel. I want to replace it for gnome-alsamixer volume changer. How to do it?

Comment: can you post an image of what you are seeing on your system?